# VS/C# Equivalent of Java/Eclipse "resource folder"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

While using Java in Eclipse IDE, one can add a folder to the "Build Path" using the "Add Class Folder" option in the "Libraries" tab, which allows the resources in that folder to get compiled inside the application's jar file, rather than outside or not at all.

[image: Click here to view an example].

With this, one can get the resources inside the folder as a URL via the `Class.getResource(String name)`method. I am already informed about C#'s equivalent: `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string name)` or `Assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(string resourceName)` methods, but I am not aware of C#'s "Build Path" equivalence in Visual Studio (I am using 2019, if you wished to know). **Could somebody please explain how I would accomplish Java's build path resource folder in C#?**

*(Note that I am looking to create a resource folder where anything put inside the folder would be considered an application resource. I am not looking for a way to add one or more resource files individually.)*

**Any replies would be greatly appreciated! :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research, I had found a solution for this problem. There are in fact *two* possible solutions to this issue.

---

***.NET Core Solution***

*The first involves editing the `.csproj` file of your C# project. This solution is only available in .Net Core.*

You can add this code snippet to your file and change the `{PATH_TO_RESOUCE_FOLDER_HERE}` folder to your desired folder.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="{PATH_TO_RESOUCE_FOLDER_HERE}\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now any item placed in that folder will be considered an embedded resource `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string name)` method.

---

***Regular .NET Solution***

*The second method involves using a `.resx` file to encapsulate all of your resources*

In *Visual Studio 2019*, you can create a `.resx` file by right clicking on the location in your project where you wish to add the file to, and navigating to `Add > New Item` (you may also press `Ctrl+Shift+A`). You can now navigate to the item that quotes "Resources File" and select it. You can now use this GUI to insert your resources (for a deeper explanation, click on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKCm3p9Gp9M) or [this](https://youtu.be/fFC8dxtPfp4?t=106) link. For use cases, see this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps)).

[The "Resources File" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2H6u.png)

Note that this solution will also work in .NET Core.

---

***I hope this answer helped you as much as it did me! :)***

Answer (score 0):

You just create a folder and name it as you like it, say 'Resources'. Add any file you want in there to be treated as a resource by your application.

Then navigate to the properties of every resource file (you can press F4) and in the menu you can choose what you want the compiler do with that file (*Compile Action* is the option name if I remember well). There you select the type as a resource, the namespace (your Build Path), and whether you like the file to be copied every time you compile your application, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was searching for a way to avoid this, since my resources folder might have many files and changing the "Compile Action" for each one would be a bit tedious, which is why I wanted a resource folder and not many resources files, but I could use this as my last resort. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Okey... then you can use a resource file (.resx). It's a different approach but you can store any type of data. Take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps)